# Ironpython shell colors

Tags: python, powershell, logging, colors, ironpython

I would like to use terminal colors with IronPython. More specifically, I'm using Windows 7 PowerShell with IronPython 2.7.4 and I would like my logging message to print with different colors.

I was able to user colors with the logging package on PowerShell using colorama with Python, but unfortunately I have to convert my script to run with IronPython and it seems that the colorama doesn't work with it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Gur

Comment: Found the solution. Within the colorama package, the file "initialise.py" at line 56, it should be:         "on_windows = sys.platform.startswith('win') or sys.platform.startswith('cli')" instead of         "on_windows = sys.platform.startswith('win')"

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Within the colorama package, the file "initialise.py" at line 56, it should be:

```
on_windows = sys.platform.startswith('win') or sys.platform.startswith('cli')
```

instead of:

```
on_windows = sys.platform.startswith('win')
```